# Different java versions uses java web start on one computer

Tags: java, jvm, java-web-start

I have searched the forum for my question but have not found the precise info i need..

I have two web start applications that uses 2 different versions of java.. How is it possible for these to work on the same computer one app using version 1.6.0_30 and the other 1.8.

Comment: have a look at Waratek multi-tenant JVM http://www.waratek.com

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP files for the two apps.?

Comment: Hi Andrew, here is the jnlp file for the web start that uses 6.30
http://comtrader-prod.epexspot.com/old/eex_ct.jnlp
http://comtrader-prod.epexspot.com/old/eex_ct_prod.html

Comment: No one who can help on this? It would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Inside the .jnlp file you will find attribute [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html). Value assigned to it inform what Java Web Start is required to use the application.

Java is backword compatible so having only version 8 you will be able to run something dedicated to version 6.

Java allows to have multiple versions on single machine and also mange them.

Comment: Hi Vash - thanks for answering:-) how should i edit the jnlp file here: comtrader-prod.epexspot.com/old/eex_ct.jnlp
so it is compatible wiht my java 8 version installed

Comment: It can be accessed/download here: comtrader-prod.epexspot.com/old/eex_ct_prod.html